# ios app works on device but not in the simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, xcode8

I rename the iOS project, after rename I update the Mac OS 10.11 to 10.12, Xcode 8.2 to 8.3. Now I run the project in device which is works fine with new app name. Where as it fails in simulator, simulator remains in booting process long time. Please suggest any solution.

Comment: try reinstall you simulator

Comment: Which simulator are you trying to run app ?

Comment: i tried in all simulators but no luck